# Compact mapping one to many in anorm

Tags: scala, orm, anorm

I have two entities.

**Good**

```
case class Good(
  var id: Long = null.asInstanceOf[Long],
  var name: String,
  var cost: Money = Moneys.ZERO,
  var category: String,
  var goodComponents: List[GoodComponent] = List.empty
)
```

**GoodComponent**

```
case class GoodComponent(
  var id: Long = null.asInstanceOf[Long],
  var goodId: Long = null.asInstanceOf[Long],
  var product: Product,
  var productAmount: Int
)
```

Now, I load goods like this:

```
 DB.withConnection(implicit connection => {
      SQL("""
        select
          goods.*, good_components.*, products.*
        from
          goods
        left join good_components
          on goods.good__id = good_components.good_component__good_id
        left join products
          on good_components.good_component__product_id = products.product__id
        order by
          goods.good__id
      """)
      .as(GoodMapping ~ (GoodComponentMapping ?) *)
      .groupBy(_._1)
      .map({
        case (good: Good, goodComponents: List[(Good ~ Option[GoodComponent])]) => {
          good.copy(goodComponents = goodComponents.map({case (_ ~ goodComponent) => { goodComponent }}).flatten)
        }
      })
      .toList
      .sortWith(($1, $2) => $1.id < $2.id)
    })
```

**GoodMapping**

```
  val GoodMapping = {
    get[Long]("good__id") ~
    get[String]("good__name") ~
    get[Int]("good__cost_rubles") ~
    get[Int]("good__cost_kopeks") ~
    get[String]("good__category") map {
      case goodId ~ goodName ~ goodCostRubles ~ goodCostKopeks ~ goodCategory => Good(
        goodId,
        goodName,
        new Money(
          goodCostRubles,
          goodCostKopeks
        ),
        goodCategory,
        List.empty
      )
    }
  }
```

**GoodComponentMapping**

```
  val GoodComponentMapping = {
    get[Long]("good_components.good_component__id") ~
    get[Long]("good_components.good_component__good_id") ~
    get[Long]("good_components.good_component__product_id") ~
    get[Int]("good_components.good_component__product_amount") ~
    get[Long]("products.product__id") ~
    get[String]("products.product__name") ~
    get[Long]("products.product__units") ~
    get[String]("products.product__category") map {
      case goodComponentId ~ goodComponentGoodId ~ goodComponentProductId ~ goodComponentProductAmount ~ productId ~ productName ~ productUnit ~ productCategory => GoodComponent(
        goodComponentId,
        goodComponentGoodId,
        new Product(
          productId,
          productName,
          ProductUnits.byId(productUnit).getOrElse({
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product unit #{" + productUnit + "} not found.")
          }),
          productCategory
        ),
        goodComponentProductAmount
      )
    }
  }
```

I think that need to create on mapping and load goods like

```
SQL("...").as(GoodMapping *)
```

I want to get advise. Is this better then I do now? How to more elegantly map good (with goodComponents list)?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this with Anorm. Anorm just maps rows to rows, and doesn't have a mechanism for collapsing multiple rows from joins into one, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Anorm is not an ORM, so doesn't provide such automagic behaviour, but can handle it using streaming to aggreagate data exactly as you need.